# pthread parallel not working as intended

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

My computer class is covering threads and parallelism in POSIX. For my lab assignment in class, we are asked to create a C program named **search** in Linux that functions similarly to bash command "grep -R" for a set of files/directories passed in as arguments. However, we must use threads and achieve parallelism in processing the text searches.

We are asked to fork a new thread whenever we encounter a file (to search it) and to recursively call search in the main thread when we reach a subdirectory.

I tried approaching the problem this way

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

pthread_t array[1000000]; // high number just to be safe
int current = 0; // current amount of threads.. should only be accessed by initial thread (main)
// so i dont think mutex is necessary..? im not sure though

struct arguments
{
    char* pattern;
    int file_index;
    char* file_name;
};


char* remove_newline(char* line)
{
    int i = strlen(line)-1;
    if ((i > 0) && (line[i] == '\n'))
    {
        line[i] = '\0';
    }
    return line;
}
void print_match(char* file_name, int file_index, int line_number, char* line)
{
    printf("%d %s %d %s\n", file_index, file_name, line_number, line); // will this work in parallel threads?
}

void add_all_matching_lines(char* pattern, int file_index, char* file_name)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return; // error checking, gotta deal with this later
    }
    int line_number = 1;
    char line[10256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        if (strstr(line, pattern) != NULL)
        {
            print_match(file_name, file_index, line_number, line);
        }
        line_number++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void* thread_work (void* ptr)
{
    struct arguments* parameters;
    parameters = (struct arguments *) ptr;
    add_all_matching_lines(parameters->pattern, parameters->file_index, parameters->file_name);
    free(parameters);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void search(char* pattern, int file_index, char* file_name)
{
    struct stat buffer;
    if (stat(file_name, &buffer) == -1) // also occurs if file is unreadable
    {
        return;
    }
    if (buffer.st_mode & S_IFREG )
    {        
        struct arguments* struct_test = malloc(sizeof(struct arguments));
        struct_test->pattern = pattern;
        struct_test->file_index = file_index;
        struct_test->file_name = file_name;
        pthread_create(&array[current], NULL, thread_work, (void *) struct_test);
        current++;
    }
    else if (buffer.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
    {
       DIR* directory = opendir(file_name);
       struct dirent* file;
       while ((file = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
       {
            if ((strcmp(".", file->d_name) < 0) && (strcmp("..", file->d_name) < 0))
            {
                char test[2] = "/";
                char buffer[1024];
                memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
                strcpy(buffer, file_name);
                strcat(buffer, test);
                strcat(buffer, file->d_name);
                search(pattern, file_index, buffer); // recursive call if it's a subdirectory
            }
       }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int file_index = 1;
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: search pattern file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (int i = 2; i != argc; i++)
    {
        search(argv[1], file_index++, argv[i]);
    }
    for (int z = 0; z != current; z++)
    {
        int test = (pthread_join(array[z], NULL));
        if (test != 0)
        {
            perror("pthread");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output of the command is

```
SAMPLE INPUT (note this example only creates between 3 and 6 threads)
$ search encyclopedia /usr/share/dict /usr/share/dict /usr/share/dict
SAMPLE OUTPUT (assuming the word encyclopedia is on line 345 of /usr/share/dict/linux.words)
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126576 encyclopedia
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126577 encyclopediac
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126578 encyclopediacal
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126579 encyclopedial
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126580 encyclopedian
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126581 encyclopedias
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126582 encyclopediast
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126576 encyclopedia
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126577 encyclopediac
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126578 encyclopediacal
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126579 encyclopedial
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126580 encyclopedian
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126581 encyclopedias
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126582 encyclopediast
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126576 encyclopedia
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126577 encyclopediac
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126578 encyclopediacal
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126579 encyclopedial
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126580 encyclopedian
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126581 encyclopedias
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126582 encyclopediast
(Note they can come out in any order, so I just chose the order 2 1 3 for this example.)
```

However, when I run my program my output is usually something like

```
$ search encyclopedia /usr/share/dict /usr/share/dict /usr/share/dict
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126576 encyclopedia
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126577 encyclopediac
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126579 encyclopediacal
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126580 encyclopedian
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126582 encyclopediast
1 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126581 encyclopedias
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126576 encyclopedia
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126577 encyclopediac
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126578 encyclopediacal
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126580 encyclopedian
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126578 encyclopediacal
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126579 encyclopedial
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126581 encyclopedias
2 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126582 encyclopediast
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126577 encyclopediac
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126581 encyclopedias
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126578 encyclopediacal
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126579 encyclopedial
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126576 encyclopedia
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126580 encyclopedian
3 /usr/share/dict/linux.words 126582 encyclopediast
```

or sometimes, it just stops somewhere in between those lines and ends unexpectedly.

or sometimes, it works as intended and the numbers become scrambled around.

I'm having a really hard time debugging my program and figuring out how to achieve the expected output 100% of the time. I make a thread each time I encounter a file so that the thread does the actual searching through the file while the main thread continues processing the remaining directories/files, so that searches can be parallel to each other.

Then in order to wait for all threads to complete before main exits I join them so that main won't terminate until all threads are complete.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I am not sure if it's a program error (I spent a few hours attempting to debug my program with no luck) or a conceptual error with making threads.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Fyi, this code is *begging* for a thread pool and a work queue. If a single thread is a problem, potentially one *million* threads is probably *not* the solution.

Comment: @WhozCraig No. Thread pools don't teach you how threads work. They teach you how thread pools work.

Comment: @AkitoNguyen it sounds like your code might be working fine - threads don't *always* run at the same time, it's possible that the first file thread finishes before the main thread gets around to starting the second file thread.

Comment: @immibis I never said thread pools "taught" *anything*. I said the task at hand meshed with a pool + queue. Read into that whatever you want.

Comment: "... figuring out how to achieve the expected output 100% of the time." Your output is highly likely to vary between runs because you are using parallelism with inherent races between your threads. Also, what is the number in the first column of the output meant to represent? In your expected output, how can #3 printing encyclopediac before encyclopedia be correct / desired???

Comment: There are a bunch of calls that can return errors which are not checked. I wouldn't bother with a program's misbehaviour when already such basics are lacking. BTW: One way to handle errors in `malloc()`, `pthread_create()` etc is to simply print an error and `exit()`. This isn't beautiful, but better than ignoring errors.

Comment: @WhozCraig The task at hand is obviously an exercise to learn about threads - see the first sentence. It's not an exercise to learn about thread pools.